# objc convert unix date

Tags: objective-c, unix, date

I got a small problem 
.
I have this date format from .net json output:

Date(1280471989140);

when I try to convert using

```
+ (NSDate*)dateFromUnixDate:(double)unixdate {
    NSTimeInterval unixDate = unixdate;
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixDate];}
```

but I got the wrong date back,why?

thanks

Comment: What is the point of your function? you should be using dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 directly. And that is the correct function to convert from unix timestamps into a date. What are you getting back?

Also, I just checked, and that timestamp is Sun, 17 Jul 42546 15:39:00 GMT. Welcome to the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did some checking, JSON Date format is in milliseconds since 1970, not seconds. To make this work you want to change your function to

```
+ (NSDate*)dateFromUnixDate:(double)unixdate 
{
    NSTimeInterval unixDate = unixdate / 1000.0;
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixDate];
}
```

or without a category method this can work as well

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    uint64_t jsonDate = 1280471989140UL;
 NSTimeInterval unixDate = (double)jsonDate / 1000.0;
 NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixDate];
 NSLog(@"%@",date);
}
```

Comment: uau... btw, it seems It doesn works.. I got always 1970-01-01 01:00:00 +0100

Comment: That one was the entire code. If you trim the date and give the double value does it works for you?

Comment: Just edited my answer to show my test code, this works fine, and gives the result 2010-07-30 01:38:56 -0500

Comment: NSTimeInterval is a typedef for double.  Your cast should be to double, not float.

Comment: I also should be adding UL on the end of the first piece, as its truncating. But it gets the point across